# How to show similar products in search or browse page of an e-commerce mobile app?

Tags: e-commerce, search-results, browse

[image]

Attaching a screen shot for reference which is not a very intuitive approach, in this you have to long press on the product image thumbnail for the similar products bottom sheet to appear. I thought of having a "similar products" CTA upfront on the images, but still not convinced, can someone suggest a better approach of doing it?

Comment: Why do you need to show a similar product on a search/Brose page? Usually, the Browse and Serch page has this. Showing a similar product makes sense when a user views a particular product. If they don't like it, they go on exploring similar stuff. Less likely they take this decision on a search or browse page

Answer (score 0):

Similar products to the search term or similar products to a particular product?

If it's the former, you can show similar products at the bottom of the search results, in its separate section.
For the latter, I wouldn't show similar products on the search results page. You should be showing that on the product's page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the UX perspective similarity of products can be analysed in different contexts.

***- UI context***

how to present data and where?
Similar products can be present both on **Page List** and also displaying in
**Buying process** (complementary sales - You bought jeans - so maybe You need
belt?)
There should be a CTA for easy add to bag - without routing to that similar product page.

In your UI it's not neccessary to create additional modal - just similar styles below the main product should be easier and cheaper for implementation.

***- Analytical context***

After implementation it's important to meeasure how many users in session click on similar products and taking actions with it.

***- ML context***

Where will the data for the designed element be delivered from? You can use ready-made tools that calculate the similarity.

Comment: Hi @Piotr, The similar products you're referring to under UI context are actually referred to as "Items frequently bought together". Similar products specifically address products that belong to similar category, have the same utility as the current product, or are visually similar in context of apparels/accessories.